# Create a React app with express, 'react-scripts' error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have been following this webpage: https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/creating-react-redux-express-full-stack-application-part-i-82959d847802

So the first time I ran into some issues so I thought it would be best to start from scratch.The first time I kept getting errors about 'react-scripts' is not recognized. I tried 'npm install react-scripts --save' but that didn't work so I gave up and deleted that project.

But when I made the new one it highlighted a bunch of stuff as wrong. And when I got to 'npm start' it keeps saying, 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command. My friend did this and she didn't run into this error. I am new to Node.js anything would be helpful!

things that I've tried that didn't work:

1. npm install -f
2. rm -rf node_modules && npm install
3. npm install --save react-scripts
4. npm cache clean --force
   npm rebuild
   npm install
5. I created a new workspace and it inherited the error- is there a way to delete it all and try again?

-Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using yarn. There have been some who solved it this way. I hope you can solve your problem.

```
yarn add react-scripts
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but it says that the yarn command was not found - I am using gitbash

Comment: so I just did npm install react-scripts then the error I get is "could not find a required file name: index.html"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but I restarted the system and it worked. Don't know exactly what was causing this issue might be a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

So there were two issues: first my directory needed to be updated and I didn't have the node_modules in my client folder - hope this helps anyone else!